# How to pass data between view controller and Container view using callbacks in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, container-view

I have a container view in my viewController.swift file. Now i want to pass data between Container view class and viewController.swift class. All demos are available using delegate function. But i want to perform this using callbacks. How i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The following site is a great reference for closures; http://fuckingclosuresyntax.com/

In your **UIView** declare a property to hold your closure;

```
var callback: ((CustomData) -> Void)?
```

Again in your **UIView** when you want to pass some data through that callback you can use;

```
callback?(someData)
```

Finally in your **UIViewController** you set your *UIView's* callback;

```
view.callback = { (data) in
    // perform some operations
}
```

Comment: you can replace `if..let` with `callback?(someData)`

Comment: Ah of course, I'd just quickly typed it up in Playground, I'll update my answer now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but i am talking about data from container view to viewcontroller. Container view is kind of UIViewController not UIVIew.

Comment: The file type shouldn't make a difference? If you can get a reference to either, allowing you to set up a delegate then you can get a reference to either to set a closure.